# Oracle : Delete rows with "execute immediate" and rowcount

Tags: oracle

I want to delete rows with an "Execute immediate" because the table name is in a variable.

How can I count the number of lines deleted?

I tried this, but it does not work with the `INTO v_LINE_REMOVE;`

```
v_sql := '
 DELETE /*+parallel(t,4)*/
 FROM "' || v_owner || '"."' || v_table_name ||'" t
 where t."'|| v_column_name ||'" in (
       select /*+parallel(rem,4)*/
       rem.' || v_type_data || ' 
       from ' || v_table_listeremove || ' rem 
       WHERE rem.dt_vact = '''|| v_dt_vact ||'''
 )
```

`';EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;--INTO v_LINE_REMOVE;`

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use `SQL%ROWCOUNT` after running your DML statement

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql;
v_line_remove := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
```